# How to properly get flag value from database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, flags

Imagine it like this. There is a field in my database called `flags` in which are added or removed data like this:

```
UPDATE people SET flags=flags|16 WHERE ....
UPDATE people SET flags=flags|128 WHERE ....
UPDATE people SET flags=flags&~16 WHERE ....
UPDATE people SET flags=flags&~128 WHERE ....
```

For instance this field can have value like 65536 or more or less. My question is - How to get specific flag from this field using PHP code? I mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE flags=16;
```

But the result will return all people with not just number 16 in field but it will return people with flag 65536, people with 16 but not people with 2 or 1. Which `SELECT` query should I use here in my php code or maybe some specific PHP integrated functions? Thank you.

Comment: can you clarify your question

Comment: Can you be more clear what exactly you want, especially the last part is a bit confusing ....

Comment: OK there are flags which can be combined together like 4194304, 8388608, 134221824 etc ... which can be added together to numbers like 2147485696 ... so which system in php should i use to get people who has in flags field number 8388608?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `flags` is a bitfield and you want to select rows where bit #4 (`10000`) is set

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE flags & 16;
```

This is not ideal though as you're losing out on all that referential goodness that DBs are good for.

What you should have is two new tables; `flags` and `people_flags`. The former contains all the flags (`id` and `name` columns should be sufficient). The latter contains `flag_id` and `people_id` columns, creating a *many-to-many* relationship (see [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)).

Comment: When I do your query for example like `SELECT * FROM people WHERE flags & 134221824;` it will return results also with flag 36864 ... I have field which contains all flags together and cannot change it - is there any way how to do so without creating any other tables?

Comment: Your flag system is broken in that case. [Bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) flags must be unique, fixed-width (usually single-bit) toggles in order to work correctly.

Comment: For instance `1 + 2 + 128 + 4096 = 4227` - so my flags field uses number 4227 - is there any "select" query or something in php which can select from this field everyone who has 128? so it would be also the person also with number 4227 - which contains number 128.

Comment: Yes, `SELECT * FROM people WHERE flags & 128`, just like in my original answer.

Comment: See my earlier comment. If you're getting false-positives, it is because your flag values are unusable as discrete bit-field toggles.

Comment: Yes you are right only one result with bad butfiled thank you. Working

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not correct though. You cant have just one flag that contains 16 as its not unique.

Lets say you have DB with this rows

```
name:Jhon tel:012345 email:test@test.com flags:16
name:Mike tel:012344 email:mike@test.com flags:16
name:Sarah tel:012346 email:sarah@test.com flags:2442
```

to select flags 16 from this table with using Select statement you will get two rows of data you can either use Distinct or get flags to be unique